# fallbackMethod is not getting called in hystrix

Tags: java, hystrix, circuit-breaker

I am trying to learn and implement hystrix circuit breaker.
I used below-mentioned code.

```
 @Component
 public class Utils{

 @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "readingList")
 public String getResponse(String restURL, String b){

    //get call to another micro serice
 CustomeReponse clientResponse=  restClient.get(restURL, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    return clientResponse;
}

@HystrixCommand
public String  readingList(String restURL, String b) {
    System.out.println("hello");
    return null;
}
```

Whenever there is a get call to another micro service, application throws an exception. Whereas it should execute fallbackMethod method. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please share the exception stack trace?

Comment: java.net.connetException is thrown because producer micro service is down.

Comment: Firstly, you don't need to put @HystrixCommand annotation on your fallback method. Remove it... Do you have any other code in this class? I mean do you have any code which could meddle with proxy creation of spring. That could be one of the reasons.

Comment: Try with annotating your class with `@Service` instead of `@Component'